# Site compatibility issue with default IE11 comes with Windows 10 - Hosted on Azure VM

Tags: asp.net, azure-web-app-service

We have a Dotnetnuke site hosted on Azure VM.
**Azure VM details**
 Server : Windows Server 2012 R2
 IIS: - 8
.Net Version – 4.6

Our Site(http://dev2-cms-molpower.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com/Admin/MOLPowerCMSLogin) is compatible with all standard browsers except IE11 that comes as default with Windows 10.

IE11 with Windows7 and Windows 8 are also working fine.

Problem we noticed with IE11/Windows 10 are :-

1. Error “ '__doPostBack' is undefined”
2. Error: 'WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions' is undefined
3. Don’t render script tag for webresource.axd
4. Don’t render hidden field “__EVENTTARGET” and “__EVENTARGUMENT”

After googling I under stand , IIS doesn't recognize user agent header sent by IE11.

Workaround I noticed , either apply latest server patch or update .Browser file .
I tried with updating .browser file in IIS for my site but it didn’t help me.

Not sure about which patch to apply

Comment: My environment is windows 10 IE 11, your site works fine on my local. I didn't receive any errors. Does your issue fixed?

Comment: If you click on top right links , you will see error upfront.